# PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer breaks Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Edit: solved, see my comment below.

Project organization:

```
my.package
   MyApplication.java
   spring
       MyConfiguration.java
```

`MyApplication.java`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MyApplication {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    MyApplication(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    ...

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`MyConfiguration.java`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        basePackages = "...",
        includeFilters = @Filter(
                type = FilterType.REGEX,
                pattern = "..."
        )
)
class MyConfiguration {
    private final ApplicationContext context;

    MyConfiguration(final ApplicationContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Bean
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer() {
        // For test purpose
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

This setup throws:

```
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at my.package.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:163) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [my.package.spring.MyConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0d9c3b2]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: my.package.spring.MyConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0d9c3b2.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1262) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: my.package.spring.MyConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0d9c3b2.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2554) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Using every other possible Bean type results in **no** errors.
I'm going crazy guys. Can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, but that you overwrite the default constructor of your `Configuration` Class. Spring needs a default constructor with at least package private access to instantiate the class. Add

```
MyConfiguration() {
}
```

to MyConfiguration and things will start working.

Comment: As I already said to another user, since Spring 5 (or even 4), the no-args constructor is no more required.
The problem was the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. It implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, which is a factory. Thus, the method must be static and accept no dependencies besides Environment. Factories are initialized before everything else.

Comment: Your solution does not seem to match your stack trace nor does Spring 5 match your code snippet. Spring Boot 2 certainly does not support missing default constructors in Configuration and will fail with exactly the error shown in your post.

Comment: I've been using Spring since version 4 and I assure you I never placed a no-args constructor, which I see as redundant and bad design. You can see the stackstrace, it says 5.1.4.RELEASE.
I debugged the Core and the thrown exception is not explicative of the problem, that's sure.
I even wrote that with any other Bean type, everything works fine, and now I know why

Answer (score 0):

The constructor in the configuration can have parameters and the class can be package-private.

But, your `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean has to be public and static.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(){
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

This works for me (fails if I remove static and/or public from PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer):

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {

    private final ApplicationContext context;

    WebConfiguration(ApplicationContext context) {
       this.context = context;
    }      

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(){
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```